Change color or multiple shapes in tkinter independently
I want to create a program where I can toggle the color of many squares with a mouse click. I am able to create the shapes and toggle the color.
My problem is with many squares. My "change color" function toggles the color of ALL the squares simultaneously. I understand the reason is I am using the same tag but I do not know how to use many tags with the same function.
import tkinter
from tkinter import *
import math
from itertools import cycle

# Variables
shot_colors = ['red', 'blue']
scale = 4.04
radius = scale * 50
diameter = 2 * radius
chord_length = scale * 32.5
chord_angle = 37.93
chord_angle_compliment = 360 - chord_angle
x0 = 50
y0 = 50
x1 = x0 + diameter
y1 = y0 + diameter
start = 270 + 0.5 * chord_angle


# Define a function to change the state of the Widget
def change_color(*args, colors=cycle(shot_colors)):
    canvas.itemconfig(tagOrId="shot", fill=next(colors))


root = Tk()
canvas = Canvas(root, width=1000, height=750)

# Create wafer shape, circle with flat oriented down
wafer = canvas.create_arc(x0, y0, x1, y1, start=start, extent=chord_angle_compliment, style=tkinter.CHORD, outline="black",
                  fill="gray", width=2)

# Create shot shapes, rectangle, this will be a for loop to create many shot(s)
shot1 = canvas.create_rectangle(257, 257, 277, 277, outline="black", fill="blue", tag="shot")
shot2 = canvas.create_rectangle(277, 277, 297, 297, outline="black", fill="blue", tag="shot")

# Change color of shot when clicked with mouse
canvas.tag_bind("shot", "<Button-1>", change_color)

canvas.pack()

root.mainloop()


This question is unclear. If you want each item to have a unique tag, what's stopping you from doing that?

If you only want to change the color of the 'shot' you clicked, you can use canvas.itemconfig(tagOrId='current', fill=next(colors)) instead. The ID 'current' should correspond to the canvas item you clicked. EDIT: there's an issue with this; see my comment on Bryan's answer below.

If you want the binding to only affect the item that was clicked on, you can use the tag "current".
From the official canvas documentation:
The tag current is managed automatically by Tk; it applies to the current item, which is the topmost item whose drawn area covers the position of the mouse cursor (different item types interpret this in varying ways; see the individual item type documentation for details). If the mouse is not in the canvas widget or is not over an item, then no item has the current tag.
Your function can be written to use this tag, like in the following example:
def change_color(*args, colors=cycle(shot_colors)):
    canvas.itemconfig(tagOrId="current", fill=next(colors))

Note: you need to use current only in the function and not in the bind statement. When you bind to shot, the binding will work for all objects with the tag shot.

I did encounter an issue with this, FWIW. If you toggle one square to red and then alternate clicking between the blue and red squares, they won't change.

Thanks for the replies. When I use the "current" tag it changes the color of shot1, shot2, and wafer. I want to keep the color of wafer static and toggle only the shot shapes. If I use tags "shot1" and "shot2" respectively for example I don't know how to use that in the tag_bind. Is it as simple as some string manipulation?

Update: If I use "current" as the tag only in itenconfig() and the tag_bind(), I get pretty close. The wafer still changes color so just need to figure out how to keep wafer gray always.

This works pretty well. Not sure if it is the most general or best solution. I added another itemconfig to my change color function to reset the wafer to gray every time.
import tkinter
from tkinter import *
import math
from itertools import cycle

# Variables
shot_colors = ['red', 'blue']
scale = 4.04
radius = scale * 50
diameter = 2 * radius
chord_length = scale * 32.5
chord_angle = 37.93
chord_angle_compliment = 360 - chord_angle
x0 = 50
y0 = 50
x1 = x0 + diameter
y1 = y0 + diameter
start = 270 + 0.5 * chord_angle


# Define a function to change the state of the Widget
def change_color(*args, colors=cycle(shot_colors)):
    canvas.itemconfig(tagOrId="current", fill=next(colors))
    canvas.itemconfig(tagOrId="wafer", fill="gray")


root = Tk()
canvas = Canvas(root, width=1000, height=750)

# Create wafer shape, circle with flat oriented down
wafer = canvas.create_arc(x0, y0, x1, y1, start=start, extent=chord_angle_compliment, style=tkinter.CHORD, outline="black",
                  fill="gray", width=2, tag="wafer")

# Create shot shapes, rectangle, this will be a for loop to create many shot(s)
shot1 = canvas.create_rectangle(257, 257, 277, 277, outline="black", fill="blue")
shot2 = canvas.create_rectangle(277, 277, 297, 297, outline="black", fill="blue")

# Change color of shot when clicked with mouse
canvas.tag_bind("current", "<Button-1>", change_color)

canvas.pack()

root.mainloop()


Your original binding on "shot" with answer from Bryan works fine, so I don't understand why you bind on tag "current" instead.

You should not bind to current because that will literally bind to whatever the current item is at that moment. Bind to shot, and the binding will work for all objects with the tag shot. Within the bound function you can use current to refer only to the actual shot that was clicked on.

Yes, it took me a day to catch on but I got it working with the input. Now it changes the shot color but leaves everything else alone. Thanks all.
